# How do I get OneDrive folders to show up in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, onedrive

My company uses Office365 and I want my OneDrive share to be accessible from Windows Explorer. On my old laptop, I just had a folder named `C:\Users\<username>\OneDrive - <organization name>`.  However, on my new laptop I've signed into OneDrive and I've tried saving from MS Word (desktop application) to OneDrive, but the folder does not exist yet.

I could have sworn all I had to do in order to set that up was to log in once, and it automatically created the folder and synced. It's possible some app was installed which took care of that, but I don't recall installing anything extra.

How do I get my OneDrive folder to show up in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Your OneDrive folder should be in `C:\Users\<your user name>\OneDrive`.  Which version of Windows is in question?  Do you actually have the OneDrive client installed in Windows?  If so, then when you double-click the OneDrive icon down by the clock, does it open a OneDrive folder, or does something else happen?

Comment: Windows 7.  Looks like I do not have a OneDrive icon in the tray. This is a work laptop, so maybe it was just preinstalled on the old machine but not the new one.

Comment: Yeah, that'd  do it. :)  I posted an answer with a link on where to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Windows 7. Looks like I do not have a OneDrive icon in the tray. This is a work laptop, so maybe it was just preinstalled on the old machine but not the new one.

Windows 7 doesn't include a OneDrive client (Windows 7 is older than OneDrive), so you'll have to [download it](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/) and install it.

Speak with your company's IT support for help with that.

Comment: Yep, turns out that was the issue; it must have been preinstalled on my old laptop but not the new one. Thanks